# Convert dates to epoch value on multiple columns using AWK

Tags: linux, script, awk

```
A,B,C,D
1,30/07/2014,data_n/a,data_n/a
2,30/07/2014,22/02/2018,data_n/a
3,26/02/2015,22/12/2016,28/07/2017
```

I would like to convert all dates at once to epoch format. I am trying to get the following code to work but it only outputs 2 columns.

```
gawk -F, '{for (i=1; i<=4; i++) split($i,date,"/");
           $i=mktime(date[3] " " date[2] " " date[1] " " "00 00 00"); 
           printf $i","; if (NF >=1 ) print $1; }'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're building the `for` loop like this:

> ```
> for (i=1; i<=4; i++) split($i,date,"/")
> ```

I mean this is the *entire* loop. The code that follows does not belong to the loop. After the loop the last value of `i` survives and `date` comes from the last `split`.

Most likely you want to end the loop just before (or after) `if (NF >=1 ) print $1`. And because you seem to treat `$1` differently then *maybe* you want to start from `i=2`. Since it's not clear what the output should be, I'm not sure what exact procedure you really want. Possibly this:

```
gawk -F, '{for (i=2; i<=4; i++) {split($i,date,"/");
           $i=mktime(date[3] " " date[2] " " date[1] " " "00 00 00"); 
           printf $i","} if (NF >=1 ) print $1; }'
```

Anyway I think the biggest problem here is you have

```
for ( … ) single_command
```

and you need

```
for ( … ) { multiple; commands }
```

Comment: It works well. Though it replaces "data_n/a" with "-1".

1406642400,-1,-1,1 1406642400,1519218000,-1,2 1424869200,1482325200,1501164000,3

The modified version removes the header: gawk -F, 'NR!=1 {for (i=2; i<=4; i++) if ($i!="data_n/a") {split($i,date,"/"); $i=mktime(date[3] " " date[2] " " date[1] " " "00 00 00"); printf $i","} if (NF >=3) print $1; }' test.csv

Output: 1406642400,1 1406642400,1519218000,2 1424869200,1482325200,1501164000,3

How can I keep the none date fields?
Thanks!

Comment: @IronMan Please take our short [tour] and learn the site is not a discussion forum. If you have a new question *with new requirements* then [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). Make sure it shows research effort.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to write your program with formatting – that way you might see where it is going wrong:

```c
{
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++)
        split($i,date,"/");
    $i=mktime(date[3] " " date[2] " " date[1] " " "00 00 00");
    printf $i",";
    if (NF >=1 )
        print $1;
}
```

- It should now be clear that `$i=mktime()` and `printf` statements are outside of the `for` loop

---

Here is a different approach using GNU `awk`:

```c
$ cat script.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR > 1 {
    for (i=2; i <= NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^([[:digit:]]+\/){2}[[:digit:]]{4}$/) {
            split($i, date, "/")
            $i = mktime(date[3]" "date[2]" "date[1]" 0 0 0")
        }
}
1
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
A,B,C,D
1,1406642400,data_n/a,data_n/a
2,1406642400,1519221600,data_n/a
3,1424872800,1482328800,1501164000
```

---

- Use `,` as both input and output field separator
- On line numbers greater than `1` in *file*:

  - loop `i` from `2` to `NF`
  - if the field `$i` looks like a date:

    - split into components
    - assign result of `mktime()` as the new value for that field
- Print every line

---

If dates in the input file are UTC, add *utc-flag* to `mktime()`:

```c
mktime(date[3]" "date[2]" "date[1]" 0 0 0", 1)
```